# Get ViewController from inherited UIView class

Tags: swift, swift4

If I have this extension:

```
extension UIResponder {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        return (self.next as? UIViewController) ?? self.next?.parentViewController
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
extension UIView {
    var getParentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

If I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass: UIView {

    init() {
        print("\( parentViewController == nil  )")
        print("\( getParentViewController == nil  )")
    }
}
```

Both results are null.

How I can get the implemented `ViewController` from my `UIView` without pass it as parameter (directly from the `view`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t get the view’s next responder in its `init` because it hasn’t been set yet. An appropriate time would be in `didMoveToWindow`.

Also, in your own answer, you said “…is the easier way to get the uiviewcontroller”, as if an app has only one instance of `UIViewController`, but every non-trivial app has multiple view controllers.